# Removed a reference to a Terraform module - now I can't destroy

Tags: terraform

I've removed a reference to a Terraform module, and I was hoping TF would then delete that resource - but as it can no longer find the module (its in GIT) - it doesn't know how to remove it.

Suggestions?

Given this is an automated process - I'd just expect TF to cope with it, `TF Destory` isn't really an option

```
Provider configuration not present
│ 
│ To work with module.cosmos_account.azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db (orphan) its
│ original provider configuration at
│ module.cosmos_account.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"]
│ is required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider
│ configuration is removed while objects created by that provider still exist
│ in the state. Re-add the provider configuration to destroy
│ module.cosmos_account.azurerm_cosmosdb_account.db (orphan), after which you
│ can remove the provider configuration again.
```

My reference looks like so:

```
module "cosmos_database" {
  source = "git::git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/../../azure-cosmossql_database"
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: you might be able to remove the entry from the state file with `terraform state rm module.cosmos_database` but you'll then need to manually delete the resources.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved - my module had a provider reference in it.

Removed the reference from my module - deployed.

Removed the module from my deployment - deployed and destroyed.